# How to solve error with wine "The requested FontFamily could not be found"?

Tags: 22.04, wine

On Ubuntu 22.04.2 I am using wine 6.0.3 to run a windows executable, but I get an error which seems to point to a font issue:

```
[ERROR] FATAL UNHANDLED EXCEPTION: System.TypeInitializationException: The type initializer for 'SafeMine.Common.UserInterface.DevExpressHelper' threw an exception. ---> System.ArgumentException: The requested FontFamily could not be found [GDI+ status: FontFamilyNotFound]
  at System.Drawing.GDIPlus.CheckStatus (System.Drawing.Status status) [0x001ce] in <15a0cb57e55e40adb4c5afb4c7ddc9e9>:0 
  at System.Drawing.FontFamily..ctor (System.Drawing.Text.GenericFontFamilies genericFamily) [0x0004d] in <15a0cb57e55e40adb4c5afb4c7ddc9e9>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.FontFamily..ctor(System.Drawing.Text.GenericFontFamilies)
  at System.Drawing.FontFamily.get_GenericSansSerif () [0x00000] in <15a0cb57e55e40adb4c5afb4c7ddc9e9>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Font.CreateFont (System.String familyName, System.Single emSize, System.Drawing.FontStyle style, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit unit, System.Byte charSet, System.Boolean isVertical) [0x00011] in <15a0cb57e55e40adb4c5afb4c7ddc9e9>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Font..ctor (System.String familyName, System.Single emSize, System.Drawing.FontStyle style, System.Drawing.GraphicsUnit unit, System.Byte gdiCharSet, System.Boolean gdiVerticalFont) [0x00011] in <15a0cb57e55e40adb4c5afb4c7ddc9e9>:0 
  at System.Drawing.Font..ctor (System.String familyName, System.Single emSize) [0x00000] in <15a0cb57e55e40adb4c5afb4c7ddc9e9>:0 
  at (wrapper remoting-invoke-with-check) System.Drawing.Font..ctor(string,single)
  at SafeMine.Common.UserInterface.DevExpressHelper..cctor () [0x00039] in <206f1b6e12ee4ce48597ac1c20859a1d>:0 
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
```

I found some hints [HERE](https://forums.linuxmint.com/viewtopic.php?f=47&t=293498) and [HERE](https://forum.winehq.org/viewtopic.php?t=32363) and installed the suggested package using

```
sudo apt install ttf-mscorefonts-installer
```

but it did not solve the problem. Any ideas?

Comment: Hi Alex. Have you tried to install the font to Wine? using winetricks? I am guessing that's the way to go. on wine prefix config you are able to install fonts.

Comment: Yes I tried some fonts without success. I even do not know WHAT fonts to install ... Shall I install every font?

Comment: Try debug using: `strace -f -e trace=open,openat,close wine <executable-name>` which shows all file paths that program wants to open. And `WINEDEBUG=+font wine <executable-name>` . It may be shows what missing.

Answer (score -1):

This is the menu I get when running winetricks. Hope it helps.

[image]
[image]

Comment: I know that menu, as I explained in my question. I tried to install some fonts but it did not fix my problem. Maybe you tell me exactly WHAT font to install? Or should I try to install EVERY available font?